# Can migrating of apps from one play account to another affect the push notifications

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have group of apps in the google play store and I am planning to move them to another play account.But now I want to know whether doing this will affect my push services that was registered to the past play store or will it simply work normal.

Comment: Changing owner account doesn't affect to GCM.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your client's GCM Ids stored. If you keep that on your new server the migration should have no effect on the GCM flow.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that some how google is handling the pushes for now.